# What is the difference between ctools_export_crud_load() and ctools_export_load_object()?

Tags: chaos-tool-suite

What is the difference between `ctools_export_crud_load()`, `ctools_export_crud_load_all()`, and `ctools_export_load_object()`?

In which cases should I use a function instead of the other two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`ctools_export_crud_load()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21ctools%21includes%21export.inc/function/ctools_export_crud_load/7):

> Load a single exportable object.

[`ctools_export_crud_load_all()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21ctools%21includes%21export.inc/function/ctools_export_crud_load_all/7):

> Load all exportable objects of a given type.

[`ctools_export_load_object()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!ctools!includes!export.inc/function/ctools_export_load_object/7):

> Load some number of exportable objects.

The first two are just shortcut functions to `ctools_export_load_object()` (with a bit of setup logic) `ctools_export_load_object()` is a more complicated function that can filter the required exportables by various criteria. The main point of interest as I can see it is that the first two accept a `$reset` parameter to reset the exportable(s)'s caches, whereas `ctools_export_load_object()` doesn't accept that parameter.

Basically, I'd say if the exportables you need to load can't be queried by using `ctools_export_crud_load()` or `ctools_export_crud_load_all()`, then use `ctools_export_load_object()`. Otherwise use one of the former functions, as they handle some of the necessary setup for you.